# Jquery click initialization problem

Tags: jquery, triggers

i have this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/ERTWT/2/) and i'm trying to initialize a click when the page loads

```
$(function() {
           $('.close_facebook').trigger('click');
        $('.apps3').click(function() {
        $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
            $('.like_facebook').show();
                });
        $('.close_facebook').click(function() {
        $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
            $('.like_facebook').hide();
                });
        });
```

but it wont trigger.

any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're initializing the click *AFTER* you're trying to trigger it. Try this:

```
$(function() {
   $('.apps3').click(function() {
      $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
      $('.like_facebook').show();
   });
   $('.close_facebook').click(function() {
      $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
      $('.like_facebook').hide();
   });

   //Trigger click after binding the event!
   $('.close_facebook').trigger('click');
});
```